# How to build our own Google's Call Screening(Incoming call answer bot) application?

Tags: android, performance, android-kernel

Is there any way to build our own Call screening application(Incoming call answer bot) to transfer the specific audio recording to an incoming call? To do that

1. The application should answer the call. (There is an official API to answer the phone call in recent versions of Android)
2. The application should be able to receive the voice.
3. The application should be able to transmit the recording as an outgoing voice.

Is it possible to do 2,3?

Answer (score 0):

In short - I'd be very surprised if 2 and 3 are possible because of legal issues - it is not legal to record conversations in the US (and other parts of the world, probably) and Google, like Apple, do not allow it. This is the main reason call recording has always been clunky on Android (e.g. forcing the user to use the speaker).

If applications have access to voice calls, there will not be a problem recording them

It gets worse on Android 9 onwards...